# Find reference to the document that created an html-element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm looking for A way to get reference the document that created the element from the element itself. (eg. element.creatorDocument)

In order to prevent un-relevant answers:

I'm not looking for the ownerDocument ( that can be found using '.ownerDocument' prop on the element)

**Example:**

Suppose you have two Iframes (A and B) create an element using A's document, append it to B, call .ownerDocument, you get B not A. which is correct because B is owning the document, not created it.

__

I'm looking for a way to get A, the one that created the element.

Comment: Could you better explain? A DOM only has one document, making `ownerDocument` a good answer...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: You can have multiple documents (`iframe`s for instance, different windows) and even create an element in one document then add it to another. I can't imagine why you'd need to know where it came from (and I doubt that information is available), but...

Comment: Suppose you have two Iframes (A and B) create an element using A's document, append it to B, call .ownerDocument, you get B not A. which is correct because B is owning the document, not created it.

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to save the needed info into a variable before you append it to `B`, then use that variable to do whatever it is you need to do.

Comment: add a proprietary property so that when replaceNode or adoptNode is called that is not changed, see my answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything on [`Element`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element) or [`Node`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#node) that provides that information. I wouldn't be surprised if the element doesn't have any link back to the creating document.

Comment: I care because I need to verify element's instance type. comparing 'instanceof' to otherDocument.HTMLElement for example will return 'false'.

Comment: @AdiDarachi: Ah, that makes sense. It probably means you can't use `instanceof` for what you wanted to use it for. Bit of a pain, that.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add a tracer property to see where the object created from (I'm modifying the prototype, make separate function in case you don't want to change the prototype):

```
document.constructor.prototype._createElement = function(tag){
    var retValue = this.createElement(tag);
    retValue.__creator = this;
    return retValue;
}
var x = document._createElement("div");
x.__creator; //#document
```